# Check at compile time that multiple enums have unique values

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, compile-time

I want to list error codes using multiple enums, so that I can define those enums in different files. How do I check at compile time that all values in these enums are unique?

I am currently defining enums like this:

```
constexpr int ERROR_CODE_MAX = 1000000;

#define ERRORS1_LIST(f) \
    f(IRRADIANCE_MUST_BE_BETWEEN, 103, L"message1") \
    f(MODULE_MUST_BE_SELECTED, 104, L"message2")

#define GENERATE_ENUM(key, value, name) key = value,
#define GENERATE_LIST(key, value, name) { key, name },

enum Errors1 {
    ERRORS1_LIST(GENERATE_ENUM)
    UndefinedError1 = ERROR_CODE_MAX - 1
};

// Error code 103 is defined twice; should trigger compile error
#define ERRORS2_LIST(f) \
    f(OPERATOR_MUST_BE_SELECTED, 105, L"message3")  \
    f(IRRADIANCE_MUST_BE_BETWEEN2, 103, L"message4")

enum Errors2 {
    ERRORS2_LIST(GENERATE_ENUM)
    UndefinedError2 = ERROR_CODE_MAX - 2
};

// List of all error messages
// I want to check error code uniqueness in the same place where I define this
static const std::map<int, std::wstring> ErrorMessageList = {
    ERRORS1_LIST(GENERATE_LIST)
    ERRORS2_LIST(GENERATE_LIST)
    {UndefinedError1, L"Undefined"}
};
```

Comment: As long as they are in the same translation unit the compiler should warn you if you reuse an `enum` (mine does apparently). But if they are in different translation units I don't see what the compiler can do about it. Unless you have in your `Makefile` a special compile stage that simply `#includes` all your *enum* headers just to check for clashes?

Comment: @Galik I want to check that number values are unique, not enum keys. This check could be done in a translation unit that includes all headers.

Comment: Ah well values are tricky... If it was super important I might be tempted to write a special purpose tool for it. `enum`s should be easy to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create variables using each error code in the variable name:

```
#define GENERATE_COUNTER(key, value, name) constexpr int IsErrorcodeUnique ## value = 1;

namespace {

ERRORS1_LIST(GENERATE_COUNTER)
ERRORS2_LIST(GENERATE_COUNTER)

} // namespace
```

Comment: What is the reason of using a `constexpr` and not a `define` ?

Comment: @DaanTimmer How would you use `define` here?

Comment: @DaanTimmer Redefinition of `typedef` does not cause a compile error.

Comment: It does, but only if the definition differs. Ugh guess it is a early Monday morning.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it. The compiler will not restrict the values you could assign to enums. however You could let the compiler check for the duplicate values of enum(s) using switch as following

```
    enum ERROR_LIST1
{
    ERROR1 = 1,
    IRRADIANCE_MUST_BE_BETWEEN = 103,
};


enum ERROR_LIST2
{
    ERROR3 = 2,
    IRRADIANCE_MUST_BE_BETWEEN2 = 103,
};


void TestDublicateEnumValue() 
{
    int x = 0;
    switch (x)
    {
    case ERROR1 :
    case IRRADIANCE_MUST_BE_BETWEEN:
    case ERROR3 :
    case IRRADIANCE_MUST_BE_BETWEEN2://this will generate compiler error
        break;
    }   
}
```